# Hovering DIV Box

Tags: css, html

I need to make a DIV box that hovers above my website and always need it to be in the top-right of the page. I have already tried:

```
<div align="right" id="hover" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px; right:0px; z-index:20; width:120px;">Time left:</div>
```

But it does not seem to stay in the top-right of the page :(, Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got both a `left` and a `right` attribute of 0, but a `width` of 120px.  Those can't all be applied unless your container happens to be exactly 120px wide.  Try removing the `left:0px`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the position to be 'fixed' if it will need to stay in the same spot as people scroll.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be honest, I haven't looked to much into it, but try setting your position tag to

```
style="position: fixed; ...."
```